# Array.push() doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array. For test purposes i output its contents like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
        console.log(i + ':' + array1[i]);
    }


0:String1
1:String2
```

Now i have a second array. What i want to do is push the contents of array1, into array2.

I do this with this line:

```
array2.push(array1);
```

Unfortunately, the contents aof the first array, exist in only one index of the second array. Separated by commas.

For example, if we use view the contents of the second array after the action it will be something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
        console.log(i + ':' + array1[i]);
    }


0:Old_string1
1:Old_string2
2:Old_string3
3:Old_string4
4:String1,String2
```

While i would like this outout:

```
4:String1
5:String2
```

Comment: Spread with `...`: `array2.push(...array1)`.

Comment: You could use `array2.concat(array1)`

Comment: hi, can you please elaborate with an example of input and the output you want?

Answer (score 5):

You should try with:

```
array2 = array2.concat(array1);
```

or with ES6 destructuring

```
array2.push(...array1);
```

Comment: The solution here is good, but the answer lacks an explanation of _why_ OP's current solution doesn't work. If only we could join this and gkgkgkgk's answer :)

Comment: Plus one for recommending the ES6 syntax :-)

Answer (score 4):

Array.push doesn't do that. You need [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) :

```
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var array2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];

console.log(array1.concat(array2));
// expected output: Array ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that concat creates a new array. it does not change existing ones.

Answer (score 3):

array.push will push one or more objects to the array. You can not pass a full array in the push() method, or the contents will be counted as one object. To combine the two arrays into one, use concat.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the spread operator (`...`) to destruct the values held in `array1` and push those into `array2`. Like so:

`array2.push(...array1);`

This will separate all the `strings` held in `array1` into individual values and then push them in. A nice little bit of syntactic sugar introduced in ES6.

Answer (score 1):

Use `push` and `apply`:

```
const a1 = ["all", "my", "strings"];
const a2 = ["belong", "together"];
Array.prototype.push.apply(a1, a2);
console.log(a1);
```